# Representation of rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, gr.group-theory

The endomorphisms of an abelian group form a ring under pointwise group operation and composition.  Every ring is isomorphic to a subring of the endomorphism ring of some abelian group (left module over itself).

Is every ring isomorphic to the endomorphism ring of some abelian group?  (not just a subring)

Comment: Any endomorphism ring which has characteristic $p$ must be the endomorphism ring of an $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space. But there are plenty of characteristic $p$ rings which are not of this form, for instance $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$, $k>2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's difficult to characterize rings isomorphic to an endomorphism ring of an abelian group. Interest in such problems was sparked by a problem given by Fuchs in his widely-read monograph *Abelian Groups*, cf. the excerpt below from the introduction to the [paper [1]](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2006.01.036)

> The notion of an E-ring goes back to a
>   seminal paper of Schultz [20] written
>   in response to Problem 45 in the
>   well-known book `Abelian Groups' by
>   Laszlo Fuchs [11]. In this paper
>   Schultz distinguished between two
>   possibly different approaches, the
>   first we will continue to call an
>   E-ring, while the second we shall
>   refer to as a generalized E-ring. Thus
>   a ring R is said to be an E-ring if R
>   is isomorphic to the endomorphism ring
>   of its underlying additive group, R+,
>   via the mapping sending an element r
>   $\in$ R to the endomorphism given by
>   left multiplication by r, whilst R is
>   a generalized E-ring if some
>   isomorphism, not necessarily left
>   multiplication, exists between R and
>   its endomorphism ring End(R+). Since
>   right multiplication is always an
>   endomorphism, it is not difficult to
>   see that E-rings are necessarily
>   commutative. The existence of a
>   non-commutative generalized E-ring has
>   recently been established [15], and so
>   it follows that the class of
>   generalized E-rings is strictly larger
>   than the class of E-rings.
>
> Since Schultz's original paper there
>   has been a great deal of interest in
>   E-rings and some natural
>   generalizations, see e.g.
>   [1,2,4,6,8-10,17,19,21]. A notable
>   feature of much of this recent work
>   has been the use of so-called
>   realization theorems, whereby a
>   cotorsion-free ring is realized, using
>   combinatorial ideas derived from
>   Shelah's Black Box - see e.g. [7] for
>   details of this technique - as the
>   endomorphism ring of an Abelian group.
>   This present work arose from an
>   observation of the second author in
>   response to a question from the first
>   about the existence of generalized
>   E-algebras over the ring $J_p$ of
>   p-adic integers; see [16] for further
>   details. A natural question which
>   arises, is to what extent is it
>   necessary for a ring to be
>   cotorsion-free in order to be a
>   generalized E-ring and the principal
>   objective of this work is to
>   characterize generalized E-rings
>   `modulo cotorsion-free groups.' The
>   characterization is quite elementary
>   but seems to have been overlooked
>   heretofore. It should be noted that
>   Bowshell and Schultz showed in [2]
>   that a reduced cotorsion E-ring has
>   the form  $\prod_{p \in U} {\mathbb
> > Z}(p^{k_p}) \oplus \prod_{p\in V} J_p$
>   where $U,V$ are disjoint sets of
>   primes.

[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2006.01.036) R. Gobel, B. Goldsmith.
Classifying E-algebras over Dedekind domains
Jnl. Algebra, Vol. 306, 2006, 566-575

Comment: A ring can be the endomorphism ring of an abelian group without being the endomorphism ring of its underlying additive group.

Comment: It took me more than a few minutes to correctly parse this sentence: "its additive group" refers to the ring, not to the abelian group. To paraphrase Bill Clinton, whether or not this is correct depends on what "it" is.

Comment: My intent was to point out the the historical genesis of such problems and to give an example of some nontrivial results. This helps provide an entry-point into the literature.

Comment: I edited my remark to help avoid any further confusion. 

Comment: My memory was correct, Fuchs did specify the general problem, namely "Problem 44. Find necessary and sufficient conditions for a ring (group) to be an endomorphism ring (group) of some group" in his *Abelian Groups* 1960, according to Google Books. Hence the genesis of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Exercise 2 in Chapter 1 of Krylov, Mikhalev, and Tuganbaev's *Endomorphism Rings of Abelian Groups* asks to show that $\mathbb{F}_p \times \mathbb{F}_p$ is not the endomorphism ring of any abelian group.  This is pretty clear: since $\mathbb{F}_p$ acts on the group $G$, as Kevin says $G$ must be an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space.

Comment: Since p times the identity endomorphism on $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is equal to zero, I don't see why the corresponding group $G$ would have to be cyclic.